# $ \sin(\arccos(\frac1{\sqrt3})) = \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3} $ proof

Tags: trigonometry

$$ \sin\left(\arccos\left(\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\right) = \frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3} $$

Can someone explain why this is the case?

Comment: $\sqrt{1}^2+\sqrt{2}^2= \sqrt{3}^2$

Comment: I think it would be better if you mentioned what you've tried doing, that way whoever is going to answer can direct you to the correct answer based on your method of solving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\theta=\arccos(1/\sqrt{3})$, so $\cos \theta=1/\sqrt{3}$. You want to find $\sin \theta$. Use $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$ \sin^2(\arccos(\frac1{\sqrt3}))+ \cos^2(\arccos(\frac1{\sqrt3}))= \sin^2(\arccos(\frac1{\sqrt3}))+\frac{1}{3}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution sketch: Draw a right triangle, with $1$ as the hypotenuse and $\frac1{\sqrt3}$ as one of the legs (or $\sqrt3$ as the hypotenuse and $1$ as one of the legs, same thing). Then see what $\arccos(1/\sqrt 3)$ corresponds to in that triangle, then see what $\sin$ of that represents. Once you know what you are *actually* after, you do the calculations.

Answer (score 1):

So... we first look at $\arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$ and ask ourselves "what sort of right triangle might the angle we get back describe?"

Well, remembering the mnemonic "SOH-CAH-TOA" we say that the angle we get back can be used to describe a right triangle whose **a**djacent side is of length $1$ and whose **h**ypotenuse is of length $\sqrt{3}$.

Now, armed with the knowledge that our triangle has a side of length $1$ and a hypotenuse of length $\sqrt{3}$, we can learn what the length of the remaining side is via the pythagorean theorem.  The length should satisfy $a^2+b^2=c^2$

$$(1)^2 + b^2 = (\sqrt{3})^2 \implies b^2 = 3-1 \implies b = \sqrt{2}$$

Now, we know that $\sin$ of that angle will be referring to the ratio of the length of the **o**pposite side (*which we learned to be $\sqrt{2}$*) over the length of the **h**ypotenuse (*which we learned to be $\sqrt{3}$*), so we arrive at the value of $\sin(\arccos(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}))=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$.